# Eclipse scout framework alernatives

Tags: jakarta-ee, frameworks, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-scout

I had discovred "Scout Framework" which look very intersent framework , but it has one disaventage is "not documented very well" , I search a same framworks ....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[what should I use eclipse rcp or eclipse scout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782056/what-should-i-use-eclipse-rcp-or-eclipse-scout)
The answer here recomments using Eclipse Riena, because...

> Eclipse Riena is comparable to Eclipse Scout as it is based on Eclipse
>   RCP and provides some useful abstractions.

Comment: let us know which framework is best documented: either rcp oder riena?

Comment: rcp of caurse but when I tested scout and I find it so productive than auther framework , all is organized in plugin ... just problem with configuration of data base ...else it's a perfect .

Answer (score 2):

we are trying to improve the documentation by writing a scout [book](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Book/3.9). it's ony started but the intent is to continue to add/upgrade the content from release to release.

see [here](http://tools.bsiag.com/scoutbook/latest/) to access the latest content